# How to center the box inside pages

Tags: html, css

I have a wp site page: http://www.agapegreekradio.com/on-air-personalities/

And its not center on the screen.

I have the following codes:

```
 <div class="section_inner">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
          <?php
          while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
          $id= get_the_ID();

          ?>
          <div class="inner_body">
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-4 col-lg-10 border-pr">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
              <div class="inner_page_text">
              <!-- <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>-->
               <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--<div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
              <div class="inner_right_text">
                <h4><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h4>
                <p><?php the_content(); ?>   
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>-->
          </div>

      </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php include_once('footer.php'); ?>
```

how can I center the box to the screen?

Comment: Which box you want center?

Comment: the container box. inner box.

Comment: for css edits checkout my answer

Comment: It seems like everything is in the center?

Comment: hoiw can i center the title text? http://www.agapegreekradio.com/on-air-personalities/

Answer (score 3):

May be you can add this class

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 border-pr">
```

after this div

```
<div class="inner_body">
```

Comment: hoiw can i center the title text? http://www.agapegreekradio.com/on-air-personalities/

Answer (score 2):

Let's Try this in your stylesheet

```
   margin: 0 auto;
   display : block;
   float: none;
```

Comment: margin auto will not work with grid class because it has float property

Comment: I think  (display: block;)will be the solution for this kind of problems.

Comment: no div element is by default display: block; no need to add

Answer (score 1):

I had a check in your website. The issue is because the default CSS rule for the div

`<div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-4 col-lg-10 border-pr">` is to float left.

So I just went ahead and added this style attribute inline to it `style="float:none;"` and it centered the div.

So your div must look like this

`<div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-4 col-lg-10 border-pr" style="float:none;">`
 Or you can even add some class with the same rule in it, or add the rule in the existing call, How ever you prefer.

Here is the result screen shot.

[image]

Comment: And if you want be really correct, add the `float: none` to your style.css instead of inline (inline styling is evil)

Comment: hoiw can i center the title text? http://www.agapegreekradio.com/on-air-personalities/

Comment: Just add `width:100%` to the `h2` tag. here is the result of it http://imgur.com/pnTO9ZB @RodelGarcia

Answer (score 0):

you can add enpty containers with one grid front and back so that it will be centered

```
 <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1"></div>
 <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-4 col-lg-10 border-pr"></div>
 <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove margin from your css and add `col-md-offset-1` [Bootstrap offset class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) in your html.

form example

```
<div class="col-xs-10 border-pr col col-xs-offset-1">
   <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
   <div class="inner_page_text">
      <!-- <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>-->
      <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hoiw can i center the title text? http://www.agapegreekradio.com/on-air-personalities/

Comment: @RodelGarcia remove float:left from .section_inner h2 from line no 228

Answer (score 0):

add this css:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
float: none;
```

to this html, maybe to border-pr class or add a new class to it:

```
<div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; float: none;" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-4 col-lg-10 border-pr">
```

AND more css :

```
.inner_body{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after  inner-body use the following

```
<div class="inner-body">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 border-pr" align="center">
```